# Google Sheets. Retrieve text in cell in column X, where short text in column Y matches full text in column Z

Tags: google-sheets

Can someone please help me with a query, or maybe search or vlookup or index match?

I've tried and tried and couldn't find a solution. Here's the problem:

I want to categorize all bank transactions automatically. I want to download a xlsx file from the website, copy, paste it in google sheets, and all transactions would get categorized.

Here's where it gets tricky. Some of the transactions are recurrent, and they all start with a string like "QR CODE PAYMENT: Client John 02/21" (ORIGINAL NAME). The problem with this is that they all come with a date there, and I always have to manually add them.

My idea was to create a Column with a filter/planner to categorize all transactions with strings containing "QR CODE PAYMENT" (FILTERED NAME).

So I have 1 column with all monthly original transactions, let's say, with 20 transactions. The other with the "code word" and the other with the category.

The problem is, with INDEX(MATCH) for example, I'm indexing the categories, but the match from the original name is obviously not found in the "code word". And the other way around, looking for the code word in the original, I retrieve the wrong row, since its shorter.

In my sheet, the column S has the categories with 3 rows, R has the codeword with 3 rows and all the original transactions with 12 rows in column L.

I want to set a formula with something like this in column M =INDEX(S4:S,MATCH("*"&L4&"*",R4:R,0). Tried VLOOKUP too :(

Please help!

Sincerelly,

Jotta

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QRlLbF4TT93w90EcUFrio29z8sCeyEt5p4PVi3evBP4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just to make it clear, in the sheet I found the only possible way was to extract the LEFT() string with a fixed number to get it right. It's not what I want, since I might have to change that also on a daily basis.

Comment: In a new tab can you showcase the expected output (***manually entered***) so as to get a clear picture of what is needed. Please do differentiate clearly on what are the input raw data columns and the desired output ones.

Comment: I'll get to it now, tab name will be ROCKIN. Give me a minute or two. Thanks

Comment: There's columns L,M,R,S. L is raw data original transactions from column C.

I want in the yellow column the values on blue column, when the values on red column matches the values on orange column.

I hope I'm making myself clear!

Comment: Sounds like you will need to use wildcards and even a helper column to create the name combination you suggest.

Comment: I can easily add a helper column but I have no idea on what that will help. Maybe to get the right row index? I'm thinking also a way of subtracting the rows using COUNTA, or get the position of the row. Maybe some math stuff.

Tricky one. But I'm open for anything you might throw! This could easily help a lot of people that work with bank transactions too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(L4:L,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(+tocol(index(if(search(R4:R,Σ),S4:S,)),3)))))
```

- *row_14* is kinda mismatching with your expected output

[image]

Comment: Oh my.... never ever seen that magic with map and lambda. Thank so very very much. You nailed it! I'll look into those formulas online for a deeper understanding, that might come in handy.